# How to access object in php when the identifier starts with a @ symbol?

Tags: php, json, laravel, escaping, laravel-5.4

I have a json object that looks like this:

```
{#119130 ▼
  +"@id": "1EBEF5DA"
  +"@name": "The"
  +"@renewal": "xxxxx"
  +"@languages": "Eng"
}
```

How do I access a the JSON data in php when the identifier starts with an `@` symbol?

For example trying to access it using `$var->@id` results in an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

I tried `$var->id` but it results in an `Undefined Property`.

Comment: You can try accessing it via `$var['@id']`. If this works I will add it as an answer for you.

Comment: why would the json property be prefixed with an `@`? It's not invalid, but what's the point?

Comment: @Gordon not sure why the clients developers did it this way. This is just the response I get from the clients server and was supposed to process it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep element name in one variable like `$test` and use `$var->$test` to get value like this

```
 <?php
    $arr = json_decode(json_encode(["@id"=> "1EBEF5DA"]));
    $obj = '@id';
    print_r($arr->$obj);
 ?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/844662

Or another way is `print_r($arr->{'@id'});`

Demo : https://eval.in/844662

Comment: Thanks @user2486. `$arr->{'@id'}` solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, $arr->{'@id'} worked for my usecase when accessing Microsoft Azure.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
$a = '{"@id":"123","@idx":"2232"}';
$b = json_decode($a);
print_r($b);
echo $b->{'@id'};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
$idFieldName = '@id';
$var->$idFieldName;
```